# How to let nodejs download web page quick

Tags: node.js

I use nodejs `http.get()` to download some page.But when meet some heavy page,it may slow.So, there are any method to let it quick?

```
http.get(url,function(res){
   res.on("data",function(chunk){
       data += chunk;
       console.log(chunk);
   });
   res.on("end",function(){
       console.log(data);
   });
);
```

Comment: it depends on server performance of the page :D

Comment: It gets the url resource, what is so heavy about it ? It creates a stream, it does not load the whole file at once.

Answer (score 0):

The speed at which you receive chunks of data is dependent on your network speed. The code you have displayed is the most optimal way to retrieve remote data.